# WCF Service in multiple applications with customization

Tags: asp.net, wcf, authorization, wcf-security

I have created a WCF Service for my web application. I am able to access all the functions & methods declared inside the interface. Now, I want to create a new web application with the same WCF Service but i dont want this web app should access all the functions & methods i.e resticted access. Can It Be Achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should first implement the credential-based access on WCF service i.e. multiple client application will access the WCF service using credentials. you can specify the declarative ondemand permissions on operation contract.

For example.

```
  [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand,Role = @”<Domain>\Customer”)]
```

This [Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff406125.aspx) might help you.